# run javascript in overrided new tab page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i've written a little chrome extension in order to replace the new tab page. everythings is fine, but some javascript won't run on my local html file (which replaces ntp).
i'm totally new to chrome extension. i think i miss something in the manifest. can someone please help me?
here's my manifest

```
{
    "chrome_url_overrides": 
    {
        "newtab": "inicio.html"    
    },
    "description": "Mostra una pagina vuota quando si apre una nuova scheda",    
    "incognito":"split",    
    "manifest_version": 2,    
    "name": "Nuova Scheda Vuota",   
    "version": "1.0" 
}
```

index.html  uses some xxx.js file in js folder beloging to ext folder

Answer (score 0):

I actually made an extension like this a while ago, and I simply added the script in inicio.html. Try that. Make a JavaScript file and import it into your html.

Comment: thanks for the reply i m very naive ,so looking at the scrreshot u mean including the 8 js file inside index_files folder in the index.html file in one file?
if so could u post a link explaing how to do it? thanks again!
http://ge.tt/1jvi83F1

Comment: Make a JavaScript file, put it in the same folder as index.html, and import the JavaScript inside of the html file like it's a normal html file.

Comment: I guess what @BobLiar is trying to say, inline javascript is forbidden, make sure all JS is inside separate files loaded into your HTML.