# Javascript and Chrome's New Tab (and alternate solutions)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm looking to either run javascript in a new tab of Chrome, or some alternative.  The issue here is that it won't run, and I'm stuck, even after doing a bit of looking.

I've searched on here, and there was only one response saying it's not possible, however I don't fully understand this.  After looking, I haven't found much more information on this matter.

As for any specifics - I want to toy around making a new tab extension for chrome, perhaps something fully fledged soon.  Part of it includes a clock and some other things (at least for now), and I've got a clock working on the normal page if I view it normally, but this is where things get annoying.  Load the extension into chrome, and.... nothing.  Point is, ***I want to make a new tab replacement for chrome that uses JavaScript, and currently I cannot get it to run any javascript, even something simple as a clock script.***

Now the initial information I found says that javascript does not work, but here's some things that would appear to contradict this:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override states:
*"...In addition to HTML, an override page usually has CSS and JavaScript code."*

Nowhere further down do I see it making any kind of 'exception' for new tab pages where you cannot use JavaScript.

Additionally, consider the new tab page called Cardboard - it's a really pretty Google Now styled new tab page.... yet it isn't incredibly static.  In fact, it has scripts, when I inspect the page!  Specifically, things like google-analytics-bundle.js, dependencies.min.js and cardboard.min.js (which other than the first two, this certainly looks like a script intended for the plugin, and not from google specifically so I would assume this isn't google-approved only code or something like that).

At this point, I'm stumped.  How would I be able to get javascript running on my new tab page?  Is there a difference in functionality between an unpacked and packed extension that I don't see any information about?  If this isn't possible, is there any other option I can have to substitute this?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking as it's currently written. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: I'll clarify in the question, but it's specifically I want to use Javascript in a New Tab for chrome.

Comment: You've got way more background than is necessary here, and too little actual meat - what do you mean by "it won't run"? Are you getting console errors when trying to use JavaScript? Can you give us more actual explanation of what you've tried and what's happening?

Comment: "I want to make a new tab replacement for chrome that uses JavaScript" it genuinely isn't clear what you mean. can you show some code and a reproducible issue?

Comment: Here's a question that suggests that inline JS may be disallowed but external JS may work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206356/run-javascript-in-overrided-new-tab-page